# Как пользоваться obfuscar?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, обфускация

Я пишу программу на C# в Visual Studio 2022, и мне нужно запутать этот проект. Я установил пакет Obfuscar через NuGet, создал в своем проекте файл (obfuscar.xml) и добавил туда этот код:

```
<Obfuscator>
<Var name="InPath" value="."/>
<Var name="OutPath" value="Obfuscator"/>

<Var name="RenameProperties" value="true"/>
<Var name="RenameEvents" value="true"/>
<Var name="RenameFields" value="true"/>
<Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false"/>
<Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true"/>
<Var name="UseUnicodeNames" value="true"/>
<Var name="HideStrings" value="true"/>
<Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true"/>
<Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="true"/>

<Module file="$(InPath)\File.exe" />
```

А также в «Событиях сборки» этого файла я ввел такой текст:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release "$Obfuscar" ....\obfuscar.xml
```

У меня ошибка в выводе:

```
""$Obfuscar"" is not internal or external 1> command, executable program, or batch file.

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5760,5): error MSB3073: leaving the team "if Release == Release "$Obfuscar" ....\obuscar.xml" с кодом 9009.
```

Как я могу правильно обфусцировать этот код?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936803/how-to-install-and-use-obfuscar
Кажется, нужно Obfuscar.Console.exe

Comment: @Zufir как я понял там есть много способов как это можно провернуть, но именно в этом способе как у меня он просто ругается на слово Obfuscar во вкладке "События сборки" и я не могу понять что не так

Comment: Я так понимаю, там нет Obfuscar.exe, а есть Obfuscar.Console.exe. Так что попробуйте заменить "$Obfuscar" на Obfuscar.Console

Comment: [AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/native-aot/?tabs=net7%2Cwindows) полностью защитит от декомпиляции. Но применимо не для всех типов проектов.